# How can the default zoom size be set in Opera?

Tags: opera, zoom

How can the default zoom size be set for newly opened pages in Opera?

Opening a ***new empty*** tab in Opera, pasting in a URL and pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> displays the web page at zoom level 100%. How can it be set to open at, say, zoom level 215%?

Platform: Windows XP 64-bit, Opera 9.64 and Opera 11.0.

Comment: Note: short of using addons or setting the minimum zoom level (about:config, zoom.minPercent) to a high value, there is no equivalent in Firefox. The closest is having the site specific zoom (about:config, browser.zoom.siteSpecific) turned on (the default) as the last zoom level will be remembered (and must thus be initially set to the desired zoom level for each site) and thus new tabs will probably be set to a convenient zoom level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the following URL in Opera.

```
opera:config#UserPrefs|Scale
```

Change the number, 100, to the desired zoom level, say 215, and save the new setting by pressing the `Save` button at the bottom of the page (it is a long page!).

Opera may acknowledge by

> JavaScript. <opera:config>. Setting saved. Scale. Some changes may require a restart to take effect.

Press the `OK` button. In this case, it takes effect immediately; a restart is not necessary for this change.

Answer (score 2):

This works in 10.63, I know different versions but should work > tools > preferences  > webpages > choose images and zoom settings for new tabs > click in 'Page Zoom' and set % . click oK

Comment: Yes, practically it is close enough. But it can not be set to 215%, the closest vales are 200% and 250%.

Comment: yes it is 'page zoom' have edited.

Answer (score 2):

In newer opera versions the settings link is `opera://settings/?search=Page+zoom`